# PostgreSQL. Update junction table

Tags: sql, postgresql, junction-table

I want to update my junction table's row. Not literally update, insert only new tuples and drop the ones that were not inserted.

Here's my tables:

users table

```
-----------------------
|user_id   |FullName |
-----------------------
|1      | John    |
|2      | Michael |
|3      | Bryce   |
```

addresses table

```
-----------------------------------------
|address_id|    country    |    city     |
-----------------------------------------
|    1     |      USA      |    New-York |
|    2     |     Russia    |    Moscow   |
|    3     |    Germany    |    Berlin   |
|    4     |      UK       |    London   |
```

This is the Junction table to connect the 
    two now.

"user_address"

```
------------------------
| user_id | address_id |
------------------------
|   1     |      1     |
|   1     |      2     |
|   2     |      3     |
|   3     |      1     |
```

For example I want to insert a new values in my junction and make it like this:

```
------------------------
| user_id | address_id |
------------------------
|   1     |      1     |
|   1     |      3     |
|   2     |      4     |
```

And, yeah, I can just do that:

```
DELETE FROM user_address WHERE address_id = 1;
INSERT INTO user_address VALUES (1, 3);
```

But, what if I'll have 1 million of rows, and user want to delete just one row. 
In this case I'll delete all 1 million and insert 999.999.999 only for ONE row.

So, how can I insert only new rows and drop the ones that were not inserted for me?

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL.

***UPDATE*** 
Hope this screenshots will explain my problem.
Here's my junction table:
[image]

I'm trying to update users for address - change user_id in junction:

```
UPDATE user_address SET user_id = 100 WHERE address_id = 25 RETURNING user_id
```

But if I use this query it will change both user_id to 100 when I want to have only one row with user_id = 100 
[image] 
So, question is How to avoid duplicates in junction's table update.

Comment: Please review your example data as it doesn't match the statements. Also it's not clear what you actually want and why it would be required to "_delete all 1 million (=1M) and insert 999.999.999 (=999M ???) only for ONE row_", could you explain your use-case a bit more?

Comment: @Ancoron Please, check my edit above, hope this'll explain my problem.

Comment: @Ancoron Here's a good example of sollution for my problem. - [link](https://giustino.blog/how-to-update-a-junction-table/) but it's MySQL. I need PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same as for the MySQL solution you've found, just that the syntax is different.

For the `INSERT`, you should add a `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_address_users ON user_address (address_id, user_id);
```

...and then you can use the [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause (introduced in PostgreSQL 9.5), to have the duplicate rows being ignored, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_address (user_id, address_id)
VALUES (100, 25), (101, 25), (102, 25)
ON CONFLICT (idx_address_users) DO NOTHING -- ignore duplicate new rows
RETURNING user_id;

DELETE FROM user_address WHERE address_id = 25 AND user_id NOT IN (100, 101, 102);
```

...or from the user side:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_address (user_id, address_id)
VALUES (100, 25), (100, 26), (100, 27)
ON CONFLICT (idx_address_users) DO NOTHING -- ignore duplicate new rows
RETURNING address_id;

DELETE FROM user_address WHERE user_id = 100 AND address_id NOT IN (25, 26, 27);
```

However, both of these approaches require your application to do a full load-modify-save cycle as you are dealing with complete collections here.

Besides that, the additional primary key is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

First to avoid and prevent duplicates in your "*junction table*", you need to make the rows unique by adding a constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE user_address ADD CONSTRAINT uq_user_addr UNIQUE(user_id, address_id)

-- OR if there is no primary key in your user_address table

ALTER TABLE user_address ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, address_id)
```

This will ensure that you have no duplicates in the specified table. In order to delete a single row, you will then have to specify both column values. If you want to delete all rows with a specific `user_id` then you specify the `user_id`; If you want to delete all rows with `address_id` you specify the `address_id`.